# Tensorflow2.0a : Why model.call() first then model.build() works but not in the opposite order?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have built two custom Keras layers and a custom Keras model for tensorflow2.0. I am trying to understand why the model.build() seem to set parameters which makes calling the model.call() function impossible later on with the following error in `eager::execute.py::quick_execute()`:

```py
TypeError: An op outside of the function building code is being passed
a "Graph" tensor. It is possible to have Graph tensors
leak out of the function building context by including a
tf.init_scope in your function building code.
For example, the following function will fail:
  @tf.function
  def has_init_scope():
    my_constant = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.init_scope():
      added = my_constant * 2
The graph tensor has name: ...
```

It is worth noting that I cannot call the individual layers of the models either (e.g `model.layer_1.call(input)`).

I will try to make the question as clear as possible, but the code for the model and layer is quite complex.

The code that fails:

```py
model = CustomModel(params)
model.build((1, 41)) # Builds OK
a = tf.Variable(tf.ones((1, 41))) 
print(model.call(a)) # Fails
```

Interestingly if I call `model.call()` **before** I build then there is no issue. That is, this code does not fail:

```py
model = CustomModel(params)
a = tf.Variable(tf.ones((1, 41))) 
print(model.call(a)) # Returns predictions
model.build((1, 41)) # Builds OK
print(model.call(a)) # Still works
```

My `model.build()` function is inspired from the Keras models, and maybe the issue comes from there?

```py
def build(self, input_shape=None):
   if input_shape is None:
      raise ValueError('You must provide an `input_shape` argument.')
   input_shape = tuple(input_shape)
   self._build_input_shape = input_shape
   super(CustomModel, self).build(input_shape)
   # Need to call the model with another positional argument to initialize all the layers
   self.call(tf.ones(input_shape), use_target=True)
   self.built = True
```

This behaviour is quite confusing and I am not sure if it is an issue with TF or if I am misunderstanding the role of `build()`.

I am aware TF2 is quite new and still in development, but if anyone had some insight it would be greatly appreciated ! :)